# How to get the data of 2 tables when same column name is given to 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in an SQL database. First table has columns as tabl1column1,table1column2,table1column3 and second table has table2column1,table2column2.
I want to get the data of **table2column1,table1column2,table1column3**

```
select S_No,Employee_id,Employee_name from Employee_Details order by S_No
```

**S_No must from dailyattendance table not from Employee_Details and Employee_id,Employee_name should be from Employee_Details table**
This is my query. Please edit it or solve it as my requirement.
How to solve it?
Please help.

Comment: (1) Your table description and sample code do not match.  (2) If I understand the question correctly, it is a trivial listing of columns in the `select` clause.

Comment: Please look at my updated query @GordonLinoff

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Maybe this can help you ... : `select S_No,Employee_id,Employee_name from Employee_Details, second_table order by S_No  `

Comment: @ShivaDebrown please not that you mentioned 2 tables but your `FROM` is pointing to one table `Employee_Details`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT d.S_No,e.Employee_id,e.Employee_name 
FROM employee_details AS e, dailyattendace AS d 
WHERE e.Employee_id= d.Employee_id Order By d.S_No
```

I don't see the second table but this is how you can do it. You can also use employee_details.S_No and table2.S_No but you write faster e.s_No than the whole table name.

Adapt to your query. In your query you only use one table but i wrote as you were using two

Answer (score 0):

if there is is relationship between your tables you can use `INNER JOIN` for it

```
select d.S_No, e.Employee_id, e.Employee_name
 from Employee_Details e INNER JOIN 
 dailyattendace d 
 ON e.Employee_id= d.Employee_id order by S_No
```

rember this will work only if there is proper relation between `e.Employee_id` and `d.Employee_id`